# Sort Symmetric Difference of Two Sets in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I was going through how to sort and print the symmetric difference of two sets in python when I saw this line of code:

```
ss=sorted(s1^s2)
```

where s1 and s2 are the two integer sets. ss gives the perfect required result. However I can't understand how s1^s2 works. What function does '^' this perform?

EDIT: Symmetric Difference, Suppose, s1={2,4,5,9} and s2={2,4,11,12} then ss={5,9,11,12}

Comment: `s1` and `s2` aren't sets they're lists in your example.

Comment: ^ is exclusive OR between 2 sets. It takes the values contained in only 1 set.

Comment: So, you are closing this post as duplicate and propose another duplicate as the answer to this question?

Comment: Sir, I am new in Python, I would like to know, can '^' operator be used on both lists and sets because the answers you suggested had not used '^' operator but the symmetric_difference function which I already know. Could you care to give a link where I can read about it. @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: it's the same as symmetric diffference, as written in one answer of the link

Comment: @SayangdiptoChakraborty `set` object implement the set-operations *union*, *intersection*, *difference*, and *symmetric-difference* using the following operators: `|`, `&`,  `-`, `^`. Bitwise XOR, i.e. `^` is the symmetric difference. Here's a [link to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to see all the built-in methods on set-like objects in Python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you :)